# How to use InputPhoto in Telethon?

Tags: python, telethon

I want to take nicknames and photos of all chat participants in telegram. For this I have code like this:

```
client = TelegramClient(username, api_id, api_hash)

async def dump_all_participants(channel) -> list:
    offset_user = 0
    limit_user = 100

    all_participants = []
    filter_user = ChannelParticipantsSearch('')

    while True:
        participants = await client(GetParticipantsRequest(channel,
            filter_user, offset_user, limit_user, hash=0))
        if not participants.users:
            break
        all_participants.extend(participants.users)
        offset_user += len(participants.users)

    all_users_details = []

    for participant in all_participants:
        if participant.photo is None:
            photo = UNKNOWN.STRING
        else:
            photo = participant.photo
        all_users_details.append({participant.id: [participant.username, photo]})
    return all_users_details
```

the problem is that the photo is a Telethon object. I can't get the photo out of it and I don't know how to do it

output photo: `UserProfilePhoto(photo_id=208135253786732667, photo_small=FileLocationToBeDeprecated(volume_id=257125342, local_id=230348), photo_big=FileLocationToBeDeprecated(volume_id=257125342, local_id=230350), dc_id=2, has_video=False)`

I found InputPhoto in the documentation [documentation InputPhoto](https://tl.telethon.dev/types/input_photo.html) and I hope it helps me, but the documentation does not contain examples of use and I cannot figure out how to implement it. Can someone help with a hint or an example of how to get a photo out of there?

Comment: `InputPhoto` is a type object like `int, str, list` etc.
Its not a function.

Answer (score 0):

There is method for this in telethon : [download_profile_photo](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html?highlight=download_profile_photo#telethon.client.downloads.DownloadMethods.download_profile_photo)

you can store the photo either downloading or storing it in memory for using it after.